# Excel Sql queries. Shift down instead of to the side if overlapping

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I want to know if it's possible to have tables from queries that overlap not be shifted to the side but be shifted down.

Lets say I have two queries creating tables in an Excel sheet. I am trying to make a legible report with headings for each table created.

I add the first query (Query A) I get something like this:

[image: onequery]

But when I add a second query (Query B):

[image: twoquery]

Query is shifted to the right. Is it possible to get it to shift down?

The report I have will have different parameters that when a user changes them it will increase or decrease rows, which causes occasional overlapping, which then has the table it overlaps shifted to the right.

I'm using different queries at the moment, and the only way I found of keeping them together is by using `UNION ALL` in my SQL. This works but is not nicely legible.

I've been looking into this for a while and haven't found much. Is there any way to have tables from queries that overlap not be shifted to the side but be shifted down?

Comment: Are you using an excel macro to accomplish this?

Comment: All I have at the moment is all my queries put together with UNION ALL, three cells for 3 parameters to be put in and a refresh button for the query. I am still not that familiar with excel macro, but I imagine there's probably someway to use it

Comment: How are you getting your query results into excel?

Comment: I go to the data tab in excel, I select 'From Other Sources'  and then select 'From MicroSoft Query'. From there I manually input my SQL and import the data into excel

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible, so I tried it myself.  I ran three queries and in all cases the results appeared in the place starting with the cell that was in focus.

Comment: Hmm. I could be just really unlucky. If you have them on top of each other what happens if you change a query above another slightly so that it returns more rows and would overlap the other below? You can do this by going to the Data tab, click 'Connections', choose 'Properties' for your query, go to the 'Definition' tab and edit it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only roundabout way I got this to easily work is I "UNION ALL" a blank row with the title I wanted which isn't that nice but I guess it'll do.